# Left Outjoin Linq query is giving NullReferenceException Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

For left outer join query i got the error. My query is

```
List<Ticket> ticket = _context.Ticket.ToList();
List<TicketDetail> ticketDetail = _context.TicketDetail.ToList();
List<ServiceCall> serviceCall = _context.ServiceCall.ToList();
List<Invoice> invoice = _context.Invoice.ToList();

var employeeRecord = from s in serviceCall
                     join i in invoice on s.invoiceId  equals i.invoiceId into table1
                     from i in table1.ToList()
                     join td in ticketDetail on s.serviceCallid equals td.serviceCallId into table2
                     from td in table2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join t in ticket on td.ticketId equals t.ticketId into table3
                     from t in table3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new ViewModel
                     {
                        ticketDetail = td,
                        ticket = t,
                         serviceCall = s,
                         invoice = i
                     };
```

If I use `ToList()` in place of `DefaultIfEmpty()` it is working, however not getting what value I want. So I guess something I am doing wrong at `DefaultIfEmpty()` or some exceptional handling problem over there, please guide me.

Comment: If `_context` is a DbContext the entire snippet is wrong. Loading entire tables in memory to join them is wong. Using explicit joins instead of using relations and navigation properties is wrong. It's the ORM's job to generate the JOINs in SQL based on the relations between entities. The `ServiceCall` should have an `Invoice` property and either a `Detail` or `Details` property. `TicketDetail` should have a `Ticket`. With that, all you'd need to generate the results would be to iterate over `_context.ServiceCall`, or use `SelectMany` to flatten the objects

Comment: I agree with German. Why you get a NRE: `table2.DefaultIfEmpty()` might return `null` (because this is what the default is). Then in `td.ticketId`, `td` will be null. You can also pass an explicit default value: `table2.DefaultIfEmpty(new MyClass())`

Comment: As mentioned - remove all `ToList` and post real error.